# Where to locate the Deleted Sharepoint Web Application

Tags: sharepoint

For an Experiment, I created an SP 2010 web application using Existing IIS Default web site. when delete the web application i delete both the IIS Site(Default website) and Content Database. Now i need to get back the deleted files from Default IIS web site (Normally It refers to the C:\Inetpub\wwwroot) Direcory. My Problem is i am not aware what are all the files get deleted except default.htm.

In recycle bin, I couldn't locate any files. By Default where will be the Deleted files get stored.

Remark : My SP Web application and IIS Site got deleted completely.

Comment: Deleting a web application is definitive. You have to recreate the web application and -if you have one- restore a backup of the content DB

Comment: What makes you think it's possible to recover at all?